# Is there a way to register bean without any @Produces and ect annotations Quarkus

Tags: java, quarkus, cdi, javabeans

Is there a way to register bean into bean container without any annotation like @Producer @ApplicationScoped and so on
I know there is a way for Spring https://www.baeldung.com/spring-5-functional-beans
But I can't find any way for Quarkus.
Unfortunately I have to register bean during some business case and I can't use annotation like Producer and so or
What I have as an example

```
if(isApplied){
Config configuration = configService.createConfig();
// register configuration as a bean with bean name to have ability to Inject it after
}
```

And this part of code I have not at startup. It's during rest api execution

Comment: Perhaps `Arc.container().beanManager().createBean` can be used, with the version that takes a `ProducerFatory`. I haven't tried it myself.

Comment: ArC doesn't support `ProducerFactory` and `BeanManager.createBean()` doesn't "register a bean into the container" anyway. I believe that using a producer should be possible, but the question doesn't contain a lot of details to be able to actually tell. Another option would be to write a Quarkus extension and conditionally register a synthetic bean, but that only works if the condition can be evaluated during application build. EDIT: actually, with a Quarkus extension, it would be possible to solve the problem in many other ways, but they would all require evaluating the condition during build.

Comment: @Ladicek , thank you for you suggestion but unfortunately it's not the way to solve my problem...Yeah, I've read about  synthetic bean that's supposed to be registered during build time but I need runtime registration. It's really petty that we don't have this way for Quarkus

Comment: @RobSpoor Thank you for you suggestion but it's impossible to create bean via BeanManager. There is only one interface implementation and with UnsupportedOperationException error :(

Comment: @Disteonne I would suggest to expand the question to describe the actual problem you're trying to solve. I suspect a solution exists. But in general, it is true that the set of beans is fixed at build time and cannot be affected at runtime.